# Open file dialog with filter

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I am using C++ and MFC. I need to modify Open File Dialog so only **folders** contains *.txt files must be visible. Any ideas?

Comment: Could be a new candidate for the File Open Dialog HOS. http://www.ronaldbieber.de/Interface_Hall_of_Shame/file_dialog.html

Comment: @selbie: That link is so full of uninformed opinion that it's not even funny. I do agree with you, though, that the original question is asking to implement a feature that has not gotten any usability considerations. So Oleg, stop right there, right now. Please.

Comment: @Tim, thankfully I don't think it's possible with the standard file dialog.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any experience with programming with MFC, but these are my doubts.

There is no reason to do so especially if you are going to filter folders on all possible levels. Just imagine user opens `C:` and you program starts scanning the whole disk. It would be even worse if this disk is connected through network.

That's the reason why I doubt that there is such ability in MFC, so you will have to write such a dialog and it's possible only if you decide to filter folder using only some fixed level of nesting.

Answer (score -1):

Use [`GetOpenFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and set the filter member of the OPENFILENAME struct instance appropriately.

```
char szFile[MAX_PATH];

OPENFILENAME ofn = {0};
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
ofn.hwndOwner = m_hWnd;
ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
ofn.lpstrFilter = "Text\0*.TXT\0";
ofn.nFilterIndex = 0;
ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn)) ...
```

Comment: The filter only applies to the currently selected directory. It doesn't filter directories based on their contents. As such it doesn't address the question.